# Remove admob sdk from react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

When I install react-native-firebase in my react native project, i am getting admob sdk and other sdk below. Which I am not using at all and it increases my app size.

```
"com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0"
"com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1"
"com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2"
"com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
"com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0"
"com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0"
```

is there any way i can remove all the libraries which i am not using in firebase

Comment: From where did you get the above lines of code, from your `app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 2):

Actually the libraries are not included in the the apk. it was included as compile only.

```
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.0"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
  compileOnly "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0"
```

I have added the below line by mistake in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

Now I have removed it and it works fine now